# Jenkins Mercurial How to get All files from all Changesets Included in Build

Tags: php, jenkins, mercurial

I'm quite new to Jenkins but as my project are starting to grow the need for a full CI increasing. So I'm looking to have a deploy task which will run if all passes. Now as Im using PHP for my server I don't want to publish via SSH the whole application each build. I would like to push only the files which have changed. Now in Jenkins I can get the revision but its showing me only the latest revision. I'm currently using batch file to get the variable value. What I need though is the list of changesets in the build as there could be more than one. Then use hg log -r %1:%2 --template "{file_mods}{file_adds}\n" to use from and too to get the list.

I am open to anyway to achieve this groovy/powershell or bat file. But any guidence on this would help as I'm getting somewhat lost looking through articles on the subject. I would have thought this would be a common thing so maybe Im missing something.

Thanks in Advance

Dean

Answer (score 1):

### Just dirty ideas, not ready-to-use solution

## Comments

> I would like to push only the files which have changed

Obvious question|addition: "... changed *since /this point in history/*". You have to store somehow this data (latest changeset of deploy) and provide it to Jenkins job

> use hg log -r %1:%2 --template "{file_mods}{file_adds}\n" to use

No. You can even at 1-st step use command, which'll prepare for you needed tree of files, and you have it: read `hg help archive`

## Hints

1. You can tag every passed tests and deployed changeset in order to have this information later. You can really use *any* format of tag (because latest tag will be always detectable as "latest", regardless of the name used), I recommend to select pattern, which will produce unique ids (just less headache in process), but you can have something like `hg tag -f DEPLOY` (-f for re-use existing name of tag, not the best style, but possible)
2. With tagging at last step for successful *deploy* (not build) for any tag-pattern you can always have set of changesets for deploy in the next time: it will be range from latest tag to tip. It will be

   `-r "last(tag()):tip"`
3. After all, you have command, which build tree of files to deploy, like

   `hg archive "-Iset:status('last(tag())', 'tip', added() or modified())" -X .hgtags -rtip -tfiles "PATH/TO/ROOT/OF/TREE"`

(notes: `set` construction define all files from range of changesets, read `hg help filesets`, `last(tag()), tip` is our range from above p.2, `added() or modified()` define which types have to be added to set: all changes, `-X .hgtags` exclude from archive file hgtags, which *was modified* since last tag-revision, but *not needed* on site)

4. You still have one not solved problem: if you have files in working directory, which was removed during development, you have also somehow remove it on prod-server (`hg archive` can't handle this)
5. Due to pp. 3-4, I'll recommend to think about "easy way of deploy": you can (?) have clone of repository on site-side, use working directory as site-root, and in this use-case deploy of new version to site will be super-easy as

`ssh $SERVER`

`cd $SIE-ROOT$`

`hg up`